# How to print column names as count of rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have following table

```
opposition    |   dismissals
--------------+-------------
Australia     |   lbw
South Africa  |   run_out
England       |   bowled
Australia     |   run_out
England       |   lbw
```

I want to print output as follows

```
Opposition    |  lbw  | run_out  | bowled
--------------+-------+----------+-------
Australia     |  1    | 1        | 0
England       |  1    | 0        | 1
South Africa  |  0    | 1        | 0
```

I cannot figure out how to use row values as column name and the print corresponding count. Can anyone can suggest in mysql how to do it? I am stuck at this question for days now. Even tried googling but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is called "pivoting" for when you need to google this one in the future. Lots of answers here:  [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you... I am glad to know it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. In MySQL:

```
select opposition,
    sum(dismissals = 'lbw'    ) lbw,
    sum(dismissals = 'run_out') run_out,
    sum(dismissals = 'bowled' ) bowled
from mytable
group by opposition
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... But I had a doubt, shouldn't be there "as" keyword before every column name.... That is sum(dismissals ='lbw' ) AS  lbw and so on.... I am not sure just asking...

Comment: @John: this keyword is optional.

Comment: oh ok.... I am new so didn't know about it.... Thanks for clarification...

Answer (score 0):

Considering the distinctly chosen values of `dismissals` column could differ, the dynamic pivoting might be a better alternative than the static one, such as

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT('SUM( dismissals =''', dismissals, ''' ) AS ',dismissals)
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT dismissals FROM tab ) t;
       
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT opposition,',@sql,' FROM tab GROUP BY opposition'); 


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=321f410667efded3f6111fb626536e50)</kbd>